# How to populate a full calendar with JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the **fullcalendar.io** plugin (in my ASP.NET MVC5 project) without success.

As I saw in the docs, I'm trying this:

```
function renderCalendar() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    lang: currentLangCode,
    eventLimit: true,
    eventSource :  [getEvents()]
  });
}

renderCalendar();

function getEvents() {
  var source = [{}];
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: '/home/fullevents',
    data: { myParam: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').visStart },
    success: function (data) {
      $(data).each(function (e, v) { 
        source.push({
          title: v.Title,
          start: v.Date,
          color: '#25427e'
        });
      });
      console.log(source);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert('could not get the data');
    },
  });
  return source;
}
```

The array is coming like this:

```
[
  {
    Date: "/Date(1448985600000)/",
    Title: "teste04"
  }
]
```

Am I missing something here? It throws no error in the console. It just doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's because the start is "/Date(1448985600000)/", fullcalendar expects it as a ["Moment-ish" input, ISO8601 type string](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) like '2015-12-01 10:00', or an actual Date object would work too like start: Date(1448985600000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should avoid creating synchronous XHR requests as they block the UI. Browsers are single threaded so you should try and use asynchronous calls where possible.

I believe what you're trying to achieve is already part of the FullCalendar library. There is an [events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) option which will be called when you first initialize your application and whenever you page through your calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

You just need to make sure your json is formatted according to the [Event Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) as outlined in FullCalendar's documentation.

**Example**

Below is a quick example how you can use WebApi and Fullcalendar together.

**View**

```
@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Calendar" })'
            });

        });

    </script>


}

<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

**Event Model**

This matches the Event Object that Fullcalendar have outlined in their documentation.

```
public class Event
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool AllDay { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime? End { get; set; }

    //
    // You can add the other properties if required
    //
}
```

Full calendar does not like proper case property names so we need to tell our JSON serializer to use camelcase. Add the following in your Global.asax or startup

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
```

**Web Api Controller**

```
public class CalendarController : ApiController
{


    public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        //
        // FullCalendar will keep passing the start and end values in as you navigate through the calendar pages
        //  You should therefore use these days to determine what events you should return . Ie
        //  i.e.     var events = db.Events.Where(event => event.Start > start && event.End < end);

        //
        // Below is dummy data to show you how the event object can be serialized 
        //
        var events = new List<Event>();

        events.Add(new Event
        {
            Id = "EventOne",
            Title = "My First Event",
            AllDay = false,
            Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2),
            End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)
        });

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, events, Request.GetConfiguration());

    }

}
```

**Example Response from Controller**

```
[{"id":"EventOne","title":"My First Event","allDay":false,"start":"2015-12-08T19:54:49.7938372+00:00"
,"end":"2015-12-08T23:54:49.7938372+00:00"}]
```

That should be everything you need to start using WebApi and Fullcalendar. This would obviously work just as well using MVC and return a Json result. As you page through the calendar you should notice your action being hit as the start and end days change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I performed these steps but the JSON returned for my dates looks like this: "\/Date(1519776000000)\/"